# svg path fill wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, svg

Firstly, I'm not a coder nor a developer. Just trying to learn by Googling. So you will have to explain it to me, like a 3 year old :) Sorry.

I'm not using a PNG. What I did was, create a logo inside illustrator and then save it as an SVG file. However, I edited the SVG file inside notepad and used the D value inside an example here - https://codepen.io/NickNoordijk/pen/VLvxLE

This allows creating a logo with the animation gradient. Works well as an HTML file with CSS. http://preston-filmmaking.uk/Logo.html

Now, I've searched all I could and can't find a way to use this as a logo. Of course, I need to change the file somehow.

I came across this https://jackiedelia.com/using-svg-animation-wordpress/ but again, can't make sense of this.

This is a sample of my HTML file. I just want to use this as my logo but not sure how to do it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Logo-Style.css">

<svg width="450px" height="195px">


<defs>  
<lineargradient id="logo-gradient" x1="150%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="20%" > 



<stop stop-color="rgb(236,30,36)" offset="0%" id="left"></stop>
<stop stop-color="rgb(243,124,32)" offset="100%" id="right"></stop>


    </lineargradient>
    <rect id="logo-gradient" x="0" y="100" width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:url(#mastGradient)" />




</defs>

<g>

<path fill="url('#logo-gradient')" opacity="1.00" d=" M 353.36 5.51 C 353.61 3.74 354.25 2.14 356.09 1.51 C 357.18 12.63 355.43 23.76 355.07 34.87 C 358.09 31.03 361.21 27.11 365.20 24.24 C 367.11 23.09 369.33 24.85 368.97 26.97 C 369.09 31.68 364.19 33.78 360.45 35.07 C 362.73 40.82 366.59 45.77 368.81 51.56 C 366.89 51.48 364.97 51.53 363.08 51.23 C 359.18 47.08 357.98 41.26 355.67 36.20 C 354.99 38.10 354.38 40.03 353.80 41.97 C 353.01 42.00 351.41 42.06 350.61 42.09 C 348.91 29.87 350.94 17.49 353.36 5.51 M 358.31 32.90 C 362.12 31.49 365.65 28.74 366.50 24.56 C 363.12 26.62 360.49 29.64 358.31 32.90 Z" />
```

The Header.php file has this code, and although I have tried playing with this, I cannot get it to work. I also tried using a plugin but didn't help.

```
<div class="header-bottom <?php if($circle_breadcrumbs || $circle_page_title 
){echo 'show-breadcrumb';}?>">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <?php 
            $circle_logo_header = (circle_get_meta_value('logo_header_page') 
!= '') ? circle_get_meta_value('logo_header_page') : 
$circle_settings['logo']['url'];
            ?>
                <div class="header-logo text-left">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" 
rel="home">
                        <?php
                        if (isset($circle_logo_header) && 
$circle_logo_header):
                            echo '<img class="" src="' . 
esc_url(str_replace(array('http:', 'https:'), '', $circle_logo_header)) . '" 
alt="' . esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display')) . '" />';
                        else:
                            bloginfo('name');
                        endif;
                        ?>
                    </a>
```

If you're asking me why am I using D values, well that's how I learnt :( using the codepenio site. If there is another way to do this and easy the please let me know. I would like to change the font anytime as this is only a test. I have also tried googling this but can't make sense.

Thanks

Comment: How can I answer your question in a way that you would understand? It is completely unclear how you got from an Illustrator-generated SVG file via the linked codepen to the logo file (which contains some good parts and some bad parts). I have no hints if you understand the basics of HTML, CSS and PHP. While my advice would amount to converting the logo to a self-contained SVG file and inserting it as an image into your site, what would be the steps I needed to explain? Only thing I can clearly say is the tutorial won't help you.

Comment: haha, thanks - I understand it's hard explaining to a noob. I created an SVG and then clicked on save. a window comes up called 'SVG Options' on here, it shows the type - SVG. i changed this to the created outline and basically followed the codepen tutorial and added more gradients.